# WooCommerce get product download url on receipt page

Tags: php, woocommerce, download, orders

On the template for **order-downloads.php** there is reference to the download file delivered for the order. But the reference that it uses produces an encrypted string rather than show the actual url.

```
%s = $download['download_url'];
```

In my case the download link will be a link that needs to be bookmarked, so I need the plain url. Can I instead use something like

```
$download = $order -> download_file();
```

and if so, what to use?

For testing I tried this code...

```
$testip = "";
if (!empty($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) {
            $drmip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        }

        if $testip = "136.220.152.221" {

            $testinvoice = $order->get_order_number();
            $testemail = $order->get_billing_email();
            $testproduct = $order->get_items();

            if(strstr($testproduct,"DDD")) {
                $testdownload = $order->get_downloadable_items()[0]['download_url'];
                echo "<script>alert('ID = " . $testinvoice . " \nEmail = " . $testemail . " \nURL = " . $testdownload . "')</script>";  
            }

        }
```

But I am getting an error "critical error on page"

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I have considered that and the products in question are limited to purchase one at a time. In any case we can always extract the urls from that array. But how to get it in the first place?

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I am editing in WP File Manager on the client's site. Where can I find that error log?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have only one possible download by order, you can use the following *(that gets the first downloadable item)*:

```php
$download      = reset($downloads); // Get first download item

$product = wc_get_product($download['product_id']);
$product_downloads = $product->get_downloads();
$product_download  = reset($product_downloads);
$download_link     = $product_download->get_file();

$order         = wc_get_order( $download['order_id'] );
$order_number  = $order->get_order_number();
$billing_email = $order->get_billing_email();
$customer_name = $order->get_billing_first_name() . ' ' . $order->get_billing_last_name();

// Test output
print_r('<pre>ID = ' . $order_number . ' <br>Customer name = ' . $customer_name . ' <br>Email = ' . $billing_email . ' <br>URL = ' . $download_link . '</pre>');
```

Tested and works.

Comment: $download['download_url'] already exists at line 53... but that is an encrypted string of the url and not the plain url

Comment: I have added the customer name to my answer code…